# Tomcat embedded fail to start after upgrade - setDigest is missing

Tags: java, security, tomcat, authentication, embedded-tomcat-8

in the release of 8.0.x of tomcat embedded I worked with
setDigest("SHA-1") , and in the 8.5 they removed this method 
and replaced it by CredentialHandler ,I used it like this:

```
 MessageDigestCredentialHandler handler = new MessageDigestCredentialHandler();
try {
        handler.setAlgorithm("SHA1");
        setCredentialHandler(handler);
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()).error("No such algorithim");
    }
```

but my server
still off and does not work , I got these exceptions messages:

```
IDT ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService] [main] [ERROR] - Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8100]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8100]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
    at com.bmc.aps.commonserver.CommonServerImpl.start(CommonServerImpl.java:597)
    at com.bmc.aps.commonserver.CommonServerImpl.startAndWait(CommonServerImpl.java:585)
    at com.bmc.aps.portal.Portal.startAndWait(Portal.java:228)
    at com.bmc.aps.portal.Portal.main(Portal.java:337)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1012)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)


Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getStore(JSSEUtil.java:211)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:283)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:91)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:245)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:839)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:196)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1010)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Delete the existing .keystore file and create a new keystore file.

Comment: Do you faced the same problem??